# How merge these two sql queries in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to merge below two queries and display two p_artist.id count based on the condition of each  band name but I am not getting any clue. Can anyone help me, please?

Thanks

```
Select p_band.title,count(p_artist.id) As 'Current Artists'
FROM p_artist INNER JOIN p_member ON p_artist.id = p_member.artist_id
INNER JOIN p_band ON p_band.id = p_member.band_id
WHERE p_member.leave_date IS NULL
GROUP BY p_band.title
;

Select p_band.title,count(p_artist.id) As 'Artists'
FROM p_artist INNER JOIN p_member ON p_artist.id = p_member.artist_id
INNER JOIN p_band ON p_band.id = p_member.band_id
WHERE p_member.leave_date IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY p_band.title
;


I want to display the record like this:

title           Current Artists    Old Artists
classical band     23             19
```

Comment: `display two p_artist.id count based on the condition of each band name` Please clarify what you mean by showing an example of the data AND the expected results.

Comment: To be NULL or not to be NULL, that is the question.

Comment: If you look at the two queries both are almost the same except the WHERE clause is different. On the basis of where clause I want to display 'Current Artists ' and  'Artists'  result.

Comment: Use a case statement in your select.

Comment: Could be just a UNION of the two queries. BTW this has absolutely nothing to do with php, I've removed that tag

Comment: @waterloomatt not working. Please help, I want to display the result like this
column 1      column 2      column 3 
classisal         2                     4

Comment: @ADyson Union is not the solution. I mean I want to have two-column of count ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean I want to have two-column of count ids

The requirements are not clear at all and I had originally typed a separate answer, but in light of the comment above I think you're looking for something like this.

It sums each case statement into its own column.

```
Select 
    p_band.title,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p_member.leave_date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as null_count, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN p_member.leave_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as not_null_count
FROM p_artist 
INNER JOIN p_member ON p_artist.id = p_member.artist_id
INNER JOIN p_band ON p_band.id = p_member.band_id
GROUP BY p_band.title
;
```

Comment: I have added the question. Sorry for the misunderstanding. Please check the bottom of part of my question.

Comment: Made a small edit. What exactly isn't working? What are you getting when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments and edits, you want to display the `title` and the amount of `Current Artists` and `Old Artists`. I just modified your two queries to get this;

```
  Select title, Current Artists, Old Artists from (
    Select p_band.title as title ,count(p_artist.id) As 'Current Artists'
    FROM p_artist INNER JOIN p_member ON p_artist.id = p_member.artist_id
    INNER JOIN p_band ON p_band.id = p_member.band_id
    WHERE p_member.leave_date IS NULL
    GROUP BY p_band.title ) a
    
    Join (
   Select p_band.title as ptitle,count(p_artist.id) As 'Old Artists'
   FROM p_artist INNER JOIN p_member ON p_artist.id = p_member.artist_id
   INNER JOIN p_band ON p_band.id = p_member.band_id
   WHERE p_member.leave_date IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY p_band.title ) b 
   On a.title = b.ptitle
```

The first select query it to get your `title` and `Current Artists` then `Join` the second select with the count of `Old Artists`.

Comment: But its not showing the column of "Artists"

Comment: @user3718511 please edit your question and post your table structures and expected output so we can understand your question clearly.

Comment: done. You can check in the bottom part of my question